# How can I manipulate an SVG path's opacity based on data stored in a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml, svg

I'm trying to change the opacity of paths within an SVG depending on the value of an integer stored in a database.

Would this be easier if it was done with XML or MySQL/PHP & JavaScript?

The database only holds one table with the values in it and at the moment i'm using MySQL (I intended to use PHP and JavaScript to manipulate the SVG but I don't know how to do that).

Either way, XML or a combination of MySQL and PHP, what would be the best way of doing this?

To give it some context - I'm trying to display company revenues in different regions with an interactive SVG world map.

Thanks,

Will

Comment: It does not make much sense to ask broad questions about "the best way" (tm) doing it because we can't answer them. Best ways are opinion based unless you deliver criteria in your question but you don't.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase. What possible solutions are there that allow me to manipulate the style of a certain SVG path depending on an integer from a database that contains one table? And which solution do you believe to be the simplest method?

Comment: SVG files are effectively XML files so you first of all need an XML parser. Take the one of your choice. Then locate the SVG path and change the value. Most likely simplest will be an XML parser with xpath. For SVG documents I personally would start with the DOM library. You should in any case create a miniature SVG as example in your question to better outline what you need to change.